# Wordpress how to create custom post template

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, customization, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

Wordpress how to create custom post template from parts of INDEX.php! On my Frontpage (Index.php) i have a great **Post Grid**. I would like to have this Grid **also under each post** (Under the Post Content between Comment field). I have copy some parts from the (Index.php) Code and inserted in the post.php but, the result was not satisfactorily.

I have searched everywhere but can not find a satisfying solution, which is compatible with my wordpress theme. If someone can help me, please let me know what code do you need. I would be more than happy to hear a solution!

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Under the Post Content between Comment field?, confusing your question, Explain little bit clear.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear what you mean, but I think you want to print some posts on your single.php file. To accomplished this, you'll need a [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) similar to:

```
<?php 
// the query
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post' // change as needed
);
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<!-- the loop -->
<?php while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>  <!-- Copy same structure and data as the one on the index.php file -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<!-- end of the loop -->

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

You will need to keep the same div structure and classes as the one on the index.php to make them look alike.
Good luck!